# Getting descriptions for multiple id values - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I have two tables x and y

Table x has 24 columns each of which holds a different Id value

Table Y has an Id value column and a description

I need to write a procedure, query or view that returns the descriptions for each of the 24 Id values contained in table x in the best performing way possible.

I've written a view that calls a function 24 times. The function returns the description based on the Id provided.
Whilst this works it doesn't perform particularly well.

Is there a technique I should use where this number of descriptions are required from a single table?

Here is the definition for table x (with non relevant columns removed for clarity)

```
    [DefinitiveHLATypeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
[A_X] [int] NULL,
[A_Y] [int] NULL,
[B_X] [int] NULL,
[B_Y] [int] NULL,
[Bw_X] [int] NULL,
[Bw_Y] [int] NULL,
[C_X] [int] NULL,
[DRB1_X] [int] NULL,
[DRB1_Y] [int] NULL,
[DRB3_X] [int] NULL,
[DRB3_Y] [int] NULL,
[DRB4_X] [int] NULL,
[DRB4_Y] [int] NULL,
[DRB5_X] [int] NULL,
[DRB5_Y] [int] NULL,
[DQA_X] [int] NULL,
[DQA_Y] [int] NULL,
[DQB_X] [int] NULL,
[DQB_Y] [int] NULL,
[DPA1_X] [int] NULL,
[DPA1_Y] [int] NULL,
[DPB1_X] [int] NULL,
[DPB1_Y] [int] NULL
```

Here is the definition for table y (with non relevant columns removed for clarity)

```
    [AntigenId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[AntigenDescription] [varchar](2000) NOT NULL
```

The relationship between the two tables is between the _X & _Y columns in table x and the AntigenId column in table Y

I need to return the Antigen Description for each of the _X & _Y columns in table x.

Comment: How these two tables relates to each other?

Comment: Please edit your question and post some sample data for each table and then the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any sample data in your tables, if you have a table that have 24 columns of data that you need to compare to another table there are a few ways to do this.

First, you could perform multiple joins on the table for each column similar to this:

```
select *
from tablex x
left join tabley y1
  on x.col1 = y1.id
left join tabley y2
  on x.col2 = y2.id --- add more joins
```

I don't know if joining the tables 24 times would be the most efficient, so it might be easier to perform an `UNPIVOT` on the table with 24 columns and join on that result:

```
select x.value,
  y.description
from 
(
  select value, col
  from tablex
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
  ) unpiv
) x
left join tabley y
  on x.value = y.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0bb8/7)

The `UNPIVOT` is the same as using a `UNION ALL` on `tablex` to transform the data from multiple columns into rows of data which will make it easier to join on:

```
select *
from
(
  select col1 value, 'col1' col
  from tablex
  union all
  select col2 value, 'col2' col
  from tablex
  union all
  select col3 value, 'col3' col
  from tablex
  union all
  select col4 value, 'col4' col
  from tablex
  union all
  select col5 value, 'col5' col
  from tablex
) x
left join tabley y
  on x.value = y.id
```

Based on your edit, your query would be similar to this:

```
select x.value,
  y.AntigenDescription
from 
(
  select DefinitiveHLATypeId, PersonId, value, col
  from tablex
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (A_X, A_Y, B_X, B_Y, Bw_X, Bw_Y,
                    C_X, DRB1_X, DRB1_Y, DRB3_X, DRB3_Y,
                    DRB4_X, DRB4_Y, DRB5_X, DRB5_Y, DQA_X, DQA_Y,
                    DQB_X, DQB_Y, DPA1_X, DPA1_Y,
                    DPB1_X, DPB1_Y
  ) unpiv
) x
left join tabley y
  on x.value = y.AntigenId
```

*Note: In the long term my suggestion would be to redesign the `tablex` because having a table structured in this way will make it difficult to access the data.*

Comment: Many thanks Bluefeet for unipivot suggestion. I'm trying it out now!
Appreciate what you say about the redesign but this is an established system and won't be easy (but not impossible) to make what would amount to a major change.

Comment: @Neil I can understand being stuck with system, that is why I still provided a solution.  I think an `unpivot` would be the easiest way to do this, then you only perform one join on the table.

Comment: Supplementary question - Is there a way to get col to be output even if the value is NULL?
The unpivot works for every col that has a value but if only 10 of the 24 columns has a value there are only 10 rows returned.

Comment: @Neil yes, you can write a subquery that will have `isnull()` around each column - similar to this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2ab0/2.  Then you will return a zero for the null values

Comment: Supplementary question to @Bluefeet if I you don't mind - Is there a way to get col to be output even if the value is NULL?
The unpivot works for every col that has a value but if only 10 of the 24 columns has a value there are only 10 rows returned.
Unpivot is new to me so am not familiar yet with all its nuances.

Comment: @Neil did you see this demo? -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2ab0/2  It will return even columns that have a `null` value

Comment: I've seen it now. Had tried to edit a comment after 5 minutes to add the @. As I was out of time I wrote a separate comment but you'd already replied.
Many thanks for your help

Comment: @Neil if any of the answers work for you, then be sure to accept via the check mark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A join

```
select tbl.col1ID, desc1.desc, tbl.col2ID, desc2.desc
from tbl 
join desc as desc1 
  on desc1.ID = col1ID 
join desc as desc2 
  on desc2.ID = col1ID
```

Comment: I appreciate that I could join table y 24 times but was looking to see if there was a better technique

Comment: The question asked for "best performing" and did not exclude join.

Comment: Apologies @Blam, I appreciate I should have been a little more precise in what I asked for.